# COMET chat application - IIS7 slows down over time

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7, comet, performancecounter

I have built a chat application which uses [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx) to push messages to clients (web pages) and to monitor online users and their information. Basically, the code creates and manages a custom thread pool for maintaining the list of connected users & their state.

The application was hosted on a shared hosting account (IIS6), and worked fine.

After moving the site (ASP.Net App) to a dedicated virtual server it seems I have a problem where IIS7 gets slower and slower as time passes, and my only "solution" is to restart IIS.

I am trying to look at the performance counters and have do idea on which one to look.

Comment: Can you give more information. Is the application ASP.NET Forms or MVC. Is the site running in an application pool configured to run in Classic Mode or Integrated Pipeline mode. What version of ASP.NET?

Comment: It is an Asp.Net Forms Application (not MVC), the site is running in an application configured to run in Integrated Pipeline mode.

Comment: I am using .Net version 3.5. By the way, on the IIS admin panel the ".Net Framework version" is set to: v2.0.50727. the only other option is version: v4.0.30319. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Task manager and PerMon on their own aren't going to help nail this down, you'll need to use tools that will allow you to look inside the application to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: did you manage to get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 3):

You may try performance optimization tool for IIS -> [here](http://iistuner.codeplex.com)

or

Chat sample applications in [there](http://pokein.codeplex.com)

On the other hand, perfmon can be useful : [read this article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b4d4d195-2ecb-4728-9348-6f1bfa1a1b63.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

If you have RDP access you should install a performance and memory profiler to see where the bottlenecks are happening.

The RedGate tools are pretty good and come with a 15 day free trial:

> [Performance Optimization and Debugging](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/)

The application may be blocking somewhere, it'd be well worth browsing over to [Tess Ferrandez's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) blog. She has some fantastic articles on tracking down performance and memory issues:

> [Performance issues and hangs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/tags/performance+issues+and+hangs/)
>
> [.NET Debugging Demos - Information and setup instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)